# Need opinions on variable query build up

Tags: php

I'm trying to build up some functions to variably build up queries from arrays. And i need to know whether i'm actually doing it correctly. Right now i'm wondering if this function to build a variable "WHERE" is okay, or should be improved.

Any opinions / tips are appreciated.

```
private function buildWhereFromArray($var, $array, $count)
    {
        $where = '(';
        for($i = 0; $i <= ($count - 1); $i++)
        {
            if(!is_numeric($array[$i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
            $where .= '('.$var.' = '.$array[$i].')';
            if($i != ($typeCount - 1))
            {
                $where .= ' AND ';
            }
        }
        $where .= ')';
        return $where;
    }
```

The variables should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit a resultset to, say, `foo` is `a`, `b` or `c`, you can use the mysql `IN()` function.

```
$where = "WHERE `{$var}` IN('a', 'b', 'c')";
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND` seems to be strange. Lets say `$array[0]!=$array[1]`

How it is possible to have $var=$array[0] AND $var=$array[1]

Need you OR?

Besides you can use it some shorter

```
implode(' AND ',array_filter(array_map(function($elem){
    if(!is_numeric($elem))
        return ''; //will be filtered
    return '('.$var.' = '.$elem.')';
},$arr)));
```

Comment: I'm already using an explode in an earlier step in the process, to put them in the array. Would that change the above process?

Comment: no, you should have array to change every elemnt in it. Also see to IN() example. It's better now